# do shell script with bracket within formula?

Tags: applescript

I want to create an applescript that inserts a separator into the dock. The code for that is:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array-add '{ "tile-type" = "spacer-tile"; }';killall Dock
```

I figured the easiest way to do it is by doing

```
do shell script "defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array-add '{ "tile-type" = "spacer-tile"; }';killall Dock"
```

but the Script Editor complains:

```
A identifier can’t go after this “"”.
```

How do I make a script with brackets within brackets? Better solutions for this problem are also very welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape each double quote with a backslash

```
do shell script "defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array-add '{ \"tile-type\" = \"spacer-tile\"; }';killall Dock"
```